# Nativescript 7 with Angular and Firebase xcodebuild failed with exit code 65

Tags: angular, firebase, nativescript, nativescript-angular, xcode12

Since I have updated my project on Nativecript7, I have a xcodebuild failed with exit code 65.

I have tried many things to correct this issue but nothing works.

It really seems that the error is coming from the emulator as it's coming at the very last point of the build.

I'm using Xcode V.12.1

When I try to run the project from XCode, I have the following error :
"Framework not found AppAuth"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Xcode downgrade Version 11.3.1 (11C505).

Comment: I did downgrade Xcode to V.12.1 and I still have the same error. So obviously it's not coming from the emulator. The last warning before build failed is "warning: There are no architectures to compile for because all architectures in VALID_ARCHS (i386, x86_64) are also in EXCLUDED_ARCHS (i386, armv6, armv8, x86_64, arm64e). Anyway thanks for the help.